# Javascript - textarea select word only

Tags: javascript, textarea

By default, when one double click on a word in a textarea, it will select the word AND the space after the word.

Is there a js script that can allow user to double click on a word and select ONLY the word, without the space that follows?

I've been searching high and low with no luck.

Answer (score 3):

You could add a double click event to the textarea, get the selected word, trim whitespace and then return the trimmed selected word to the user. I'm not sure if there is a better way but thats how I will probably approach it.

Answer (score 1):

+1 to Christain'n answer...

But I would add:

The double clicking behaviour may on the OS/Browser being used. A word might not be selected by double clicking on it.

Example: on windows, clicking on the address bar selects all the text but on linux, the same does not happen. I know that the browser's text field is not the same as ones rendered in HTML, but it serves to demonstrate the text field behaviour is not entirely predictable.